# How to properly share information across multiple threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am building a system that requires to share information from one thread (The first generates the information) with a second thread (socket).

How can I access the information of Detector Thread in the socketThread?
I have tried to set the variables as Global, and they can be found in the main.py file. Although I cannot access them in the socket thread.

```
from objDetect import *
from socketclient import *

import threading

   

detectorThread = threading.Thread(name='detect', target=detectorWorker)
socketThread = threading.Thread(name='api', target=runSocket)
socketThread.setDaemon(True)

try:
    detectorThread.start()
    socketThread.start()
except:
    print('[ERROR] Couldnt start detector.')
```

Comment: Sharing data between Threads: https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/handling-and-sharing-data-between-threads/ <--> building a socket server + socket client e.g. websocket https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: Thank you. The socket client is working fine.
The issue is that the data is modified by thead 1 and only read by thread 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the various thread-safe queues in the `queue` module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html